# How to highlight invalid data on gridview if validation against a DataTable is failed VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, validation, gridview, datatable, gridviewrow

I tried my best to shrink down the program to the following code. In this example, I have UK and USA as valid countries. If someone lives outside those countries, I wanna show an error message and highlight them on the gridview. For example, John and Chris are from China so they should be highlighted on the gridview.  Is it possible to do that ? Please see example picture. Either just Name or the whole row can be highlighted.

Thanks a lot.

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("ID")
    dt.Columns.Add("Name")
    dt.Columns.Add("Country")

    dt.Rows.Add("1", "John", "China")
    dt.Rows.Add("2", "Harry", "USA")
    dt.Rows.Add("3", "Joe", "UK")
    dt.Rows.Add("4", "Emma", "UK")
    dt.Rows.Add("5", "Chris", "China")
    dt.Rows.Add("6", "Jenny", "UK")


    Dim isValid As Boolean = True
    Dim keywords() As String = {"UK", "USA"}
    Dim str As String = ""

    For Each x As DataRow In dt.Rows
        If Not keywords.Contains(x("Country").ToString()) = True Then
            isValid = False
        End If
    Next

    If isValid = False Then
        lblmessage.Text = "Some people don't live in valid countries"
    End If

    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

[image]

Comment: I assume ASP.NET since a Winforms GridView is called DataGridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do that ?

Yes, one way is to use GridView's [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event. Assuming you have a list of valid countries:

```
Private validCountries() As String = {"UK", "USA"}

Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)
    Select Case e.Row.RowType
        Case DataControlRowType.DataRow
            Dim row = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row
            Dim country = row.Field(Of String)("Country")
            ' assuming you're using TemplateFields with LblName for the Name of the user '
            Dim LblName = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("LblName"), Label)
            If Not validCountries.Contains(country.ToUpper) Then
                LblName.CssClass = "InvalidCountry"
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

If you're using BoundFields instead, you need to apply the CSS on the table cell

```
e.Row.Cells(1).CssClass = "InvalidCountry"
```

Comment: Thanks Tim .. Your example is great ! I am still thinking if I can use that in my program .. infact, the validation occur in functions ... UK and USA are just example, actually it has 10+ keywords to do the validation. If I can return invalid row number of DataTable from the validation function in a array or a list, can i then be possible highlight on the gridview when binding ?

Comment: @LaurenceNyein: I've edited my answer to show how to validate against a list of countries. Or have i misunderstood your last comment?

Comment: Thanks Tim ... that will be much easier for me to work with .. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I will keep Tim's answer as a proper answer. I am really appreciate his help. This is an alternative of what we can do if someone tries to do the same thing like me. Hope it helps to someone out there.

```
    Imports System.Data

    Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("ID")
    dt.Columns.Add("NAME")

    dt.Rows.Add("1", "John")
    dt.Rows.Add("2", "Chris")
    dt.Rows.Add("3", "")

    Dim str As New StringBuilder

    If checkName(dt) = False Then
        str.Append("Empty Name <br />")
    End If

    Literal1.Text = str.ToString

    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()

    For Each gvrow In GridView1.Rows
        For iCol = 0 To gvrow.Cells.Count - 1
            If InStr(gvrow.Cells(iCol).Text, "***") > 0 Then
                gvrow.Cells(iCol).Text = Replace(gvrow.Cells(iCol).Text, "***", "")
                gvrow.Cells(iCol).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
                gvrow.Cells(iCol).BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightCyan
            End If

        Next
    Next

    End Sub

    Private Function checkName(dt As DataTable) As Boolean

    For Each x In dt.Rows
        If x("Name") = "" Then
            x("Name") = "***"
            Return False
        End If
    Next

    Return True
    End Function

    End Class
```